# How do I return an array from an OpenOffice Basic function?

Tags: arrays, openoffice.org, basic

I'm reading through the documentation on [OpenOffice regarding arrays](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays) and it seems like `Calc` is capable of array functions just like `Excel`.

To test this I created a simple function that should return an array `{1, 2, 3}`:

```
Function Test()
    Dim Test(3) As Variant
    Test(1) = 1
    Test(2) = 2
    Test(3) = 3
End Function
```

When I populate a cell with `=Test()` and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` I just get a cell with `3` in it. Where are `1` and `2`? What am I doing wrong?

I'm running `OpenOffice 4.1.1`.

Comment: Some(most) BASIC-dialects pass byref, you can use this to change an array in a sub or function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dimensioning of an function return type must be done within the `Function` statement. If the function shall return an array, then it must be dimensioned as `Variant`. There is no way in starbasic dimensioning the function as array type directly. The array itself can be created separately within the function body and then assigned to the function as return value.

Like so:

```
Function Test() as Variant
    Dim arr_Test(1 to 3) As Integer
    arr_Test(1) = 1
    arr_Test(2) = 2
    arr_Test(3) = 3
    Test = arr_Test
End Function
```

Or if you want it shorter, you could use the built-in `Array` function which returns a `Variant` containing an array.

Like so:

```
Function Test2() as Variant
    Test2 = Array(1,2,3)
End Function
```

Documentations for openoffice- / libreoffice- / -BASIC programming:

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide -> https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Basic/OpenOffice.org_Basic

But both have not fully references for BASIC basics ;-) such as references for all built-in functions.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Basic_Help -> https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Run-Time_Functions
seems to be almost completely.

Comment: Great, just one last question: How did you find out about that `Array` function? I haven't been able to find a reference for `OpenOffice BASIC`...

Comment: Good suggestion about "Variant" result type. I got XLS with macros, and one of these produced error in function declaration. The result type was declared as "byte()" which is OK in VBA. and not appropriate in "Starbasic". Inside the function the "open-dimensioned" array assigned to function result. Replacing "byte()" with "variant" made the macros working.