# Excel lookup formula not working in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, openoffice-calc, gnumeric

I recently converted a file named `template.xlsx` into `template.ods` using the command line utility called `gnumeric`. All formulas get converted correctly except this one:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Import!$F$",Q3,":$F$",M3))>=(S3)*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($S$1,"LOOKUP FACTOR x",""))),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("Import!$B$",Q3,":$B$",M3)))
```

This formula is quite long to some extent, but to keep it short I have 2 sheets, one called `Import` and the other `Lookup`. I want to return the **last** value in a specific range (and match its row in another range) that is greater than or equal to the value in `S3` multiplied by the `LOOKUP FACTOR x`, e.g. if is `LOOKUP FACTOR x2`, the value in `S3` is multiplied by 2.

I found that the way **OpenOffice Calc** accesses a range from another sheet is different to how **Excel** does, hence I rewrote the formula to:

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$F$";Q3;":$F$";M3))>=(S3)*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($S$1;"LOOKUP FACTOR x";"")));INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$B$";Q3;":$B$";M3)))
```

Hereby changing the sheetname from `Import!$F$` to `$Import.$F$`. The same for column `$B$`.

When I run this formula, OpenOffice returns the error `#DIV/0!`.

So, if I chunk up the formula into each of its parts:

- `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$F$";Q3;":$F$";M3))`
- `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$B$";Q3;":$B$";M3))`
- `=(S3)*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($S$1;"LOOKUP FACTOR x";""))`

Whenever I execute them in separate cells, I get the same results in both spreadsheet programs, which means they do **WORK** individually. This makes me believe the issue is with the `LOOKUP`.

In the above case, the reason I'm using `INDIRECT` is because both cells `Q3` and `M3` reference to the beginning and the end of a range:

`Q3` contains:

`{=MIN(IF($Import.$A$1:$A$1048576=A3;ROW($Import.$A$1:$A$1048576)-ROW(INDEX($Import.$A$1:$A$1048576;1;1))+1))}`

`M3` contains about the same but using `MAX`:

`{=MAX(...)}`

These will return the index position where an array of array starts and ends. Say that `A3` equals to `Apple`, then `Q3` will return the row of `Apple`'s first occurrence and `Q3` will return the row of `Apple`'s last occurrence in `Column A`.

It's worth reiterating that **ALL** formulas work except the `LOOKUP`, meaning that the above *cell references* `B3` and `M3` return the correct index position (or row). It's also worth mentioning that the formula does work for Excel.

Does anyone know why the `LOOKUP` formula does not work in OpenOffice?

Can this be done elsewise without `LOOKUP`?

Comment: It could be due to the Difference in cell notation of Excel and OO.  If I remember right, OO uses semi-colon in formulas, where as excel uses comma.

Try to set your OO to use Excel A1 notation under Tools>Options>Calc

Comment: But seems you have thay taken care of, can you try concatenating using & instead of the Concatenate option?

Comment: Hi @JPAlpano As I said the `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$F$";Q3;":$F$";M3))` works individually. So changing the `CONCATENATE` to `&` will give me the same result. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how it works in Excel, but in Calc, `>=` simply returns true if the value on the left is greater than or equal to the value on the right.  So it sounds like we need to add an `IF` statement to do what you are asking.

The following [array formula](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Using_Arrays#Array_formulas) finds the highest row where the condition returns true.  Then it grabs the value from that cell.

```
=INDIRECT("Import.F"&MAX(IF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$F$";Q3;":$F$";M3))>=S3*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($S$1;"LOOKUP FACTOR x";""));ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$F$";Q3;":$F$";M3)));0)))
```

Breakdown:

- **INDIRECT(** - grab the value from that cell
- **"Import.F"&** - this plus the row makes the address we're looking for
- **MAX(** - get the highest row number that works, because we want the last value in the range
- **IF(** - if the value is greater or equal, then return the row number, otherwise return zero
- **INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$F$";Q3;":$F$";M3))>=S3*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($S$1;"LOOKUP FACTOR x";""))** - returns true if the value is greater or equal, otherwise false
- **;ROW(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("$Import.$F$";Q3;":$F$";M3))** - get the row we are currently looking at.  This could be shortened to `CREATEARRAY(Q3;M3)` by implementing a user-defined function that [returns an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190901/how-do-i-return-an-array-from-an-openoffice-basic-function) of row numbers.
- **;0** - return row number as zero if not greater or equal

Comment: Works like a charm @JimK  I changed the return column to another range `=INDIRECT("Import.B"` which is what I needed. Thanks for the concise follow up!