# OpenOffice Calc - External Workbook Reference returns "Err:504"

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula, openoffice-calc, array-formulas

Basically this is a continuation of my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058436/excel-lookup-formula-not-working-in-openoffice-calc). I thought I should ask this separately as this issue is *external  references* related. I have the following formula that **works** in OpenOffice 4.1.2:

```
{=MAX(IF($Data.$A$1:$A$1048576=A3;IF($Data.$F$1:$F$1048576>=W3*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($W$1;"LOOKUP FACTOR x";""));ROW($Data.$F$1:$F$1048576))))}
```

According to @JimK who helped me develop and simplify this formula in the first place, this returns the **last** row in `Column F` (`$Data.` being an individual sheet) that is greater than or equal to the value in `W3` multiplied by the `LOOKUP FACTOR x`, only `IF` the values in `Column A` equal to `A3`.

The issue I'm having is that now instead of referencing to the sheet `$Data.`, I want to replace each `$Data.` instance with an external workbook reference `[data.xlsx]DATA!`. Example:

```
{=MAX(IF('file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$A$1:$A$1048576=A3;'file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$D$1:$D$1048576))}
```

This array formula **works** and returns the `MAX` price in `data.ods'#$DATA.$F$1:$F$1048576` only `IF` the range `data.ods'#$DATA.$A$1:$A$1048576` corresponds to the value in cell `A3` which is for instance `Apples` (see Note). The value in cell `A4` in this case would be `Bananas`, and so on.

The following array formula **works** in Excel Mac 15.12.3:

```
{=MAX(IF('/Applications/.../[data.xlsx]DATA'!$A:$A=A3,IF('/Applications/.../[data.xlsx]DATA'!$F:$F>=W3*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($W$1,"LOOKUP FACTOR x","")),ROW('/Applications/.../[data.xlsx]DATA'!$F:$F))))}
```

The following array formula, however, **doesn't work** in OpenOffice 4.1.2:

```
{=MAX(IF('file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$A$1:$A$1048576=A3;IF('file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$F$1:$F$1048576>=W3*VALUE(SUBSTITUTE($W$1;"LOOKUP FACTOR x";""));ROW('file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$F$1:$F$1048576))))}
```

Neither does a different scenario:

```
{=MAX(IF('file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$A$1:$A$1048576=A3;ROW('file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$A$1:$A$1048576)-ROW(INDEX('file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.$A$1:$A$1048576;1;1))+1))}
```

For the above array formula obviously `{=MIN(IF(...))}` does not work either.

They both return the same [error](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/General_error_codes):

`Err:504 - Error in parameter list`

It seems to be that somehow OpenOffice Calc does not read the *domain reference* to the external workbook properly, but for other formulas it **works** (like the one mentioned above). Given my research, [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=3294) is where I originally got my syntax for referencing by file-URL. I also came across this [post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=42632) which states that `Err:504` may be due to that literal strings are "double quoted".

So I went ahead and replaced:

`'file:///Applications/.../data.ods'#$DATA.`

with

`"file:///Applications/.../data.ods"#$DATA.`

which evidently returned

`Err:509 - Missing Operator`

---

Does anyone know how I can reference the external (and closed) workbook inside an array formula with nested `IFs` like in the examples above?

---

**Note**: It's worth mentioning:

- The table within sheet `$Data.` is grouped by `Column A` which contains the name of the products e.g. grouped by `Apples` then `Bananas`, etc.
- `Column B` in `$Data.` contains dates which are sorted into descending order.
- `Column F` in `$Data.` contains prices for each product on different dates.
- The rest of the columns simply contain product metadata and descriptions which may also vary depending on the date.

All of the above also apply for `'/.../data.ods'#$DATA.`.